# Items in ComboBox

Tags: java, combobox

I am tying to perform and action when an item in combo box are selected, but it performs an action no matter what item is selected.Can someone help me out please.

```
//number of players combo box
        players = new JComboBox();
        contentPane.add(players, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        players.addItem("1 Player");
        players.addItem("2 Players");
        players.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

         @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         makeFrame();
        }
       });
       players.addItem("3 Players");
//end of combo box
```

Comment: What do you want? you want to call `makeFrame` if value is 1 or 2 players.

Comment: You'll need to determine which item was selected and perform the action you want based on that information. ActionPerformed is executed when ever the selected item in the field changes...

Comment: Yes, i want to makeFrame() if item 2 is selected.. and not just when any other item is selected

Comment: @user3507763 By "item 2", do you mean `"2 Players"`, the second item in the list (still `"2 players"`) or item at index 2 (`"3 Players"`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to change behavior based on which item was selected, you will need to retrieve the selected value inside your `ActionListener` and change the behavior based on the selected value. You could use something like the following:

```
//number of players combo box
//notice that you have to declare players
//as final. If it is a member of the class,
//you can declare it final in the field
//declaration and initialize it in the
//constructor, or if local, just leave it
//as it is here. Unless using Java 8, then it
//doesn't need to be declared final
final JComboBox players = new JComboBox();
contentPane.add(players, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
players.addItem("1 Player");
//your combo box still needs to be final
final JComboBox players = new JComboBox();
contentPane.add(players, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
players.addItem("1 Player");
players.addItem("2 Players");
players.addItem("3 Players");
players.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String selectedValue = String.valueOf(players.getSelectedItem());
        if (selectedValue != null && (selectedValue.equals("1 Player") || selectedValue.equals("2 Players"))) {
            makeFrame();
        }
        else {
            //do something else
        }
    }
});
//end of combo box
```

If you happen to know the index ahead of time (i.e., you statically initialize the list of options instead of dynamically generating the list), you could also just refer to [`.getSelectedIndex()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedIndex%28%29) to retrieve the index as follows:

```
//number of players combo box
//the combo box still needs to be final here
final JComboBox players = new JComboBox();
contentPane.add(players, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
players.addItem("1 Player");
//your combo box still needs to be final
final JComboBox players = new JComboBox();
contentPane.add(players, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
players.addItem("2 Players");
players.addItem("3 Players");
players.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int myIndex = players.getSelectedIndex();
        if (myIndex == 0 || myIndex == 1) {
            makeFrame();
        }
        else {
            //do something else
        }
    }
});
//end of combo box
```